# How to merge two nginx rewrite rules into one?

Tags: regex, nginx

nginx rewrite rule:

```
rewrite ^/([a-z]+)$ /?type=$1 last;
rewrite ^/([a-z]+)/page/([0-9]+)$ /?type=$1&page=$2 last;
```

can I merge these two rules into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it but something like this might work..

```
^/([a-z]+)/?(page/([0-9]+)|)/?
```

---

**Edit**: here's the full block:

```
location ~ /(blog)/?(page/([0-9]+)|)/? {
  default_type 'text/plain';
  echo "$1";
  echo "$2";
  echo "$3";
}
```

Going to **/blog** produces

```
blog
```

Going to **/blog/page/3** produces

```
blog
page/3
3
```

**$3** will have the page number if it's been specified otherwise it will be empty.

Comment: thanks marco,I didn't know how to write `/?type=$1&page=$2` this part